# Creating a RectangularGrid

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a little out of my depth with an assignment and am trying to do a basic constructor for a rectangular grid:

```
public RectangularGrid(int x, int y) {

    if ((x == 0) || (y == 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Grid <T> grid = new RectangularGrid<T>(x, y);
}
```

But this seems to be failing the tests I have been given, in that it gives a stack overflow. I really don't see what is going wrong here, it seems really basic.

The test is the following:

```
private RectangularGrid<GameObject> grid;

/**
 * Create a small RectangularGrid to be used for testing.
 * The grid is 3 cells in length and 4 cells in width.
 */
@Before
public void setupRectangularGrid() {
    grid = new RectangularGrid<GameObject>(3, 4);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You are recursively creating a new `RectangularGrid` in your `RectangularGrid` constructor. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the same method (constructor) within the constructor itself. Thus, rather than ever return, your code will simply call your constructor over and over again until you have a stack overflow exception